# I loged onto the phpmyadmin. After loging in i am get the error.

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running please?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html) the MySQL documentation about `lc_messages` variable. This is what it says:

> As of MySQL 5.5, the server searches for the error message file using
>   these rule...

So, it's likely that you are using an older MySQL version than 5.5 and hence, it can't recognise this variable.

Comment: i am using version 5.5.  how can i rectify it

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you have to run MySQL > 5.5 to set lc_messages.
Maybe this will help: [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)