# Can't connect to MySQL: Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, wamp

Last week I was working without problem in a laravel project with a MySQL database in the localhost and two days ago when I tried to connect to phpmyadmin this message appeared:

> Error
>   SQL query: Edit Edit
>   SET lc_messages = 'en_US';

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

I have made my research in internet, uninstalled wamp, deleted the wamp folder and reinstalled the newest version,

I found and followed these instructions:

- [#1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages' when trying to login to phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084464/1193-unknown-system-variable-lc-messages-when-trying-to-login-to-phpmyadmin)
- [I loged onto the phpmyadmin. After loging in i am get the error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360220/i-loged-onto-the-phpmyadmin-after-loging-in-i-am-get-the-error)
- [Unknown system variable when opening phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541077/unknown-system-variable-when-opening-phpmyadmin)

Nothing worked.

I've checked the `my.ini` file and it is configured as expected:

```
lc-messages-dir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.19/share"  
lc-messages=en_US
```

And my laravel project is not working because it can't connect to MySQL either.
 I'm working on a Windows 10 computer and my installed versions are:

- PHPMyAdmin 4.7.4
- MySQL 5.7.19
- WAMP 3.1.0
- PHP 7.1.9

I really have no idea what else to do, I just want the project to work and any help is really appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**: To be clear, I have already checked other stackoverflow questions on this subject and they didn't work, that's why I asked this question

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate of a question that the OP clearly states he already read and tried?